# Continuity of the improper integral $\int_{0}^{x}y^{-1/2}dy.$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

The improper integral $\int_{0}^{x}y^{-1/2}dy$ is

$1.$ Continuous on $[0,\infty).$

$2.$ Continuous on $(0,\infty).$

$3.$ Continuous only on $[1/2,\infty)$

It is cleat that option $3$rd is wrong one. I am confused about $1$st and $2$nd option. I tried it as $$\int_{0}^{x}y^{-1/2}dy=2\sqrt{x}$$ so it is continuous on $[0,\infty).$ But i am confused about the point that the function $\int_{0}^{x}y^{-1/2}dy$ is not defined at $0$ so not continuous at $0.$ Please suggest me . Thanks a lot.

Comment: You discuss about continuity of $F$ where $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(y) dy$$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki   yes but $f$ is not defined at $0.$

Comment: $F(0)=0$ . Now find $\underset{x\to {{0}^{+}}}{\mathop{\lim }}\,F(x)$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki How $F(0)=0?$ this is my main doubt.

Comment: $\int_a^a = 0$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @par whatever g(x) may be it is always $\int_{a}^{a}g=0?$

Comment: By definition of Riemann Integral

Comment: But Riemann integral is only for Proper integral.....

Comment: $g(y)=y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ just has one discontinuity point on  $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: Sir i may be irritating you asking again and again ...sorry for that...but the concept of Riemann integral is only for bounded function on a bounded domain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion was leading you to the correct answer:  $2\sqrt{x}$ is not defined at $x<0$ so the limit from the left does not exist so that integral cannot be continuous at $x=0$.  Then number 2 is the right answer.

This is the answer in real analysis, where the domain to be considered is the netire real line and you have to care about the limit from the left of zero.  If your universe were $\Bbb{R}^+ \cup 0$ then you would have to say that the function is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Bur $\sqrt{x} $ is always continuous at $0.$

Comment: @Msrk Fisheler in question it is asked in the domain $[0,\infty)$. It means it is continuous on $[0,\infty)$